# Customising Google Map marker

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I'm using some code i got from Codepen for placing some pointers on a Goole map.

It's currently using the default markers but id like to change them to my own ones, but i'm not really sure where to updated the code for this. Any examples would be very much appreciated

Here is the the code - http://jsfiddle.net/MSLRr/

Each pointer is placed by this code:

```
var data = [ // map data
      {
        'id':1,
        'content':'Hello my name is marker, I\'m from Google',
         'position': {
          'lat':55.86423,
         'lng':-4.251
         }
      },
      {
        'id':2,
        'content':'I am the content of this infobox. Wow, what a text.<br><br><a href="#">The good thing is: Tags are also possible</a>',
        'position': {
          'lat':55.874,
          'lng':-4.25
         }
      },
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use icon property of the marker (google dev reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons)

```
var data = [ // map data
{
    'id':1,
    'content':'Hello my name is marker, I\'m from Google',
    'position': {
        'lat':55.86423,
        'lng':-4.251
    },
    'icon': 'youricon.png'
},
{
    'id':2,
    'content':'I am the content of this infobox. Wow, what a text.<br><br><a href="#">The good thing is: Tags are also possible</a>',
    'position': {
        'lat':55.874,
        'lng':-4.25,
    },
    'icon': 'youricon.png'
}]
```

And using the new property icon in your data array to markers

Comment: so by adding in that one line you added what else do i need to add and where exactly to ? Thanks

Comment: as you can see in google documentation, in the marker definition add `icon` property and set it by `icon` property of `data` item. you can see the update here: http://jsfiddle.net/MSLRr/1/

Comment: that jsfiddle didn't seem to work until i updated 'icon': 'youricon.png' to an actual link to an image

Comment: I don't have any marker image now, it's just a sample code that you can reuse in your code

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that... On another small note, would you happen to know how to automatically close the currently opened popup info when another pointer is selected to view the details?

Comment: Google documentation says that infoWindow remain opened until user interaction but you can track the opening of a new infoWindow and closing the other one with the `close` method. (ref. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)

Comment: If you only ever want one infowindow, only create one (globally) and use that (change the content and open it on the clicked marker).  How to automatically close the currently opened infowindow when another is opened is a duplicate question.

Comment: hmm I'm not quite following. Is there any chance you can edit the jsfiddle